# Space between two words are getting lost after assigning php variable to javascript variable

Tags: php, javascript

I have created two simple files in php.

first file (i.e. input.php ):

- Created one form having one textbox and one submit button
- I have one textbox, user will add input in this textbox
- One submit button, after clicking on this form will get submit ( used post method )

Second file (process.php) :

- Posted contents are received here.
- Assigning textbox ( from $_POST supergloble variable ) value to javascript variable.
- And displaying this javascript value

What I observed after submitting below content in first file

**Input :**

```
Hi this is test
Hello world
```

After displaying value using javascript value I am getting below content

**Output :**

```
 Hi this is testHello world.
```

the 'test' and 'Hello' words are getting concatenated.

below is my code from process.php :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var display = <?php echo $_POST['textareaInput']; ?>
    alert(display);

    </script>
```

I wanted to know whether assignment of php variable to javascript variable is right ?

Can anybody please let me know, what is the root cause here ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Id hope that var display = <?php echo $_POST['textareaInput']; ?> has some quotation marks somewhere, and that you're escaping any quotes in $_POST['textareaInput']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to  assign a string to a variable, so you should mark it as a proper string:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var display = "<?php echo addslashes($_POST['textareaInput']); ?>";
alert(display);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var display = "<?php echo addslashes($_POST['textareaInput']); ?>";
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to replace the line-breaks, here is what you can do (handling also the quotes if there are some) :

```
 $input = preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "\\n", addslashes($_POST['textareaInput']));
```